# How to navigate through data via Sqllite and ListActivity

Tags: android, sqlite, listactivity, listadapter

I'm displaying data from SQLite using

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            employees,
            new String[] {"FirstName","LastName"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},0);
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

empoyees - my Cursor.

Data is showing correctly, but how to get what row I used from SQLite duaring OnClick on my item from List?
For example I have 2 tables

```
1)Category
_id Integer
Name Text

2)Articles
_id Integer
Name text
CategoryId (foreing key)
```

So on first screen I'm displaying all Categorys, then on list item click I want to display Articles that are from specified category, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use your cursor in your adapter. Build up an array and send in the array instead. In that array, typically something like `List<MyDataRecordHolder>` (where MyDataRecordHolder is an object you've created and filled with data from the database), you will have to set a reference to a row id.

UPDATE:

Create your MyDataRecordHolder: (Pseudo code)

```
List<MyDataRecordHolder> list = new List<MyDataRecordHolder>();
```

in your loop where you fetch data:

```
MyDataRecordHolder record = new MyDataRecordHolder();
record.setId(cursor.get("rowid"))
//set any other pertinent data
list.add(record);
```

For your adapter:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        list,
        new String[] {"FirstName","LastName"},
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},0);
```

Note, you are now supplying the List (list) to the adapter.

In your OnClick for your row, in the adapter, you will get the current MyDataRecordHolder:

```
final MyRecordHolder record = getItem(position);
String id = record.getId();
//make new db query based on your id
```

Comment: So MyDataRecordHolder will be something like Entity?

Comment: It would be whatever you make it to be. Just create a simple class with holders and call it (for example) MyRecordHolder. Add the data from your class where your have your cursor. When the entire database row is read, put that object (MyRecordHolder myRecordHolder) in a list.